# Abrir arquivo xls (protegido por senha) em Delphi e salvar dados em tabela Firebird

Tags: delphi, firebird, microsoft-office

Tenho um arquivo do office (*.xls*), protegido por senha, que possui diversas linhas.

Quero fazer uma busca pelo conteúdo da coluna *1* e sabendo a linha que se encontra o resultado quero salvar esta única linha em uma tabela do banco de dados Firebird.

Exemplo:

Digamos que a tabela seja de dados de empresas. No caso eu gostaria de saber o nome da empresa e tenho o *CNPJ* dela. Assim sendo, vou utilizar um `for` (acredito) e rodar em todas as linhas até achar o *CNPJ* que informei, e após isso vou pegar o conteúdo do campo *Razão Social*.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Deve aparecer uma requisição da senha. Realmente CSV não tem senha, vou alterar a pergunta pois preciso de um arquivo com senha.

Comment: @GiovaniRaciPaganini É necessário mostrar a janela para colocar a senha? ou pode ser programaticamente? Outra coisa, você quer pegar o valor de apenas uma linha?

Comment: @QMechanic73 eu quero apenas de uma linha, buscando pelo conteúdo que a coluna 1 apresenta em todas as linhas. Quando a senha é indiferente, porque qualquer coisa posso adequar mais tarde.
Caso não tenha entendido me avise que posso exemplificar.

Comment: @GiovaniRaciPaganini Mas a senha pode ser inserida via código? Você quer pegar o valor da linha *X* coluna *Y* correto? Quando você diz: *eu quero apenas de uma linha, buscando pelo conteúdo que a coluna 1 apresenta em todas as linhas.* Você já sabe a coluna e a linha que têm que pegar certo? se possível explique melhor essa parte. =D

Comment: @QMechanic73 A senha pode ser inserida via código sim.
Exemplo: digamos que a tabela seja de dados de empresas. No caso eu gostaria de saber o nome da empresa e tenho o CNPJ dela. Assim sendo, vou utilizar um FOR (acredito) e rodar em todas as linhas até achar o CNPJ que informei, e após isso vou pegar o conteúdo do campo 'Razão Social'

Comment: @GiovaniRaciPaganini Ok, você já sabe a coluna do *CNPJ da empresa* e a coluna da *razão social*?

Comment: @GiovaniRaciPaganini Recentemente fiz uma implementação utilizando planilhas protegidas e exportação dos dados. Mas no entanto não consegui entender a sua dúvida, já que isso não foi exatamente uma pergunta. Sua dúvida é o processo todo? É como ler o arquivo protegido? Como buscar o conteúdo na planilha? Poderia esclarecer?

Comment: @QMechanic73 já sim

Comment: @ArthurdeAndrade A minha duvida é tanto como ler os arquivo protegido como buscar os dados.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento acabei de entrar aqui: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21137/discussion-between-user3465632-and-guilherme-nascimento

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21232/abrir-arquivo-xls-protegido-por-senha-em-delphi-e-salvar-dados-em-tabela-firebi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso pode ser feito através da arquitetura [**Component Object Model**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> O *Component Object Model* (COM) é uma arquitetura de software que permite que aplicativos sejam construídos a partir de componentes de software binários. COM é a arquitetura subjacente que constitui a base para serviços de software de alto nível, como os prestados por [OLE](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Linking_and_Embedding). Ela é usada para permitir a comunicação entre processos e a criação dinâmica de objetos em qualquer linguagem de programação que suporte a tecnologia.

[**OLE Programmatic Identifiers**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa219391(v=office.11).aspx) - Lista de componentes que podem ser criados por OLE.

No Delphi é possível criar esse tipo de componente através da função [`CreateOleObject`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Win.ComObj.CreateOleObject), para usá-la é necessário incluir a unidade [ComObj](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Win.ComObj) em [*Uses*](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Uses).

Para criar uma aplicação Excel é necessário usar o identificador `Excel.Application`.

Indo direto ao assunto, a função abaixo vai abrir o arquivo, procurar por um determinado valor (CNPJ), se encontrar pega o valor desejado (*Razão social*) da outra coluna (*Nome da Empresa*).

```pascal
// Inclua em Uses: ComObj;
function GetExcelValue(const xlsPath: string; const CNPJToSeach: string; const Pass: string = ''): string;
const
 xlCellTypeLastCell = $0000000B; // Mais informações em: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx
 ColunaCNPJ    = 1; // Define a coluna aonde será feita a busca pelo CNPJ
 ColunaEmpresa = 2; // Nome da Empresa
var
 ExcelApp, FileName, Password, ReadOnly: Variant;
 Cols, Rows, I, C: Integer;
 RangeMatrix: Variant;
 TempStr: string;
begin
Result := '';
try
  // Cria a aplicação Excel.
  ExcelApp := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  // É especificado o arquivo, a senha, e informamos que esse processo é somente leitura.
  ExcelApp.WorkBooks.Open(FileName := xlsPath, Password := Pass, ReadOnly := True);

  // Ativa a última célula não vazia, necessário para obter o número de linhas e colunas.
  ExcelApp.ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell, EmptyParam).Activate;

  Cols := ExcelApp.ActiveCell.Column; // Número de colunas
  Rows := ExcelApp.ActiveCell.Row;    // Número de Linhas
  // Coloca em RangeMatrix os valores desde A1 até a faixa de colunas e linhas encontradas.
  RangeMatrix := ExcelApp.Range['A1', ExcelApp.Cells.Item[Rows, Cols]].Value;
  I := 1;

  repeat
    for C := 1 to Cols do // Percorre as colunas
      // Verifica se a linha atual correnponde ao CNPJ procurado.
      if RangeMatrix[I, ColunaCNPJ] = CNPJToSeach then begin
        // Se encontrar, obtêm a linha da coluna desejada
        TempStr := VarToStrDef(RangeMatrix[I, ColunaEmpresa], '');
        Break; // Encerra o loop
      end;

      Inc(I, 1);
    until I > Rows;
    Result := TempStr;
finally
  RangeMatrix := Unassigned;
  ExcelApp.Quit;
end;
end;
```

Para usá-la especifique o local do arquivo Excel, o CNPJ a procurar, e a senha (*opcional*).

Veja um exemplo:

Supondo que a planilha tenha a seguinte estrutura:

```all
 ______________________________________________________________________
| CNPJ  | Razão Social | Nome da Empresa | Município | NIRE | Endereço |
|-------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+------+----------|
| 000-1 | Foo          | Empresa-1       | Mun-1     | 1110 | End-1    | 
| 000-2 | Bar          | Empresa-2       | Mun-2     | 2220 | End-2    |
| 000-3 | Baz          | Empresa-3       | Mun-3     | 3330 | End-3    |
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

E você deseja obter o nome da empresa cujo CNPJ é *000-2*, para fazer isso chame a função `GetExcelValue` da seguinte forma:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.BtnRetrieveValueClick(Sender: TObject);
const
 EXCELFILEPATH = 'c:\Foo\Bar\ArquivoX.xlsx';
var
 ExcelValue: string;
begin
if FileExists(EXCELFILEPATH) = false then exit;

ExcelValue := GetExcelValue(EXCELFILEPATH, '000-2', 'senha123');

// Fazer algo com o valor obtido daqui em diante.
end;
```

Em situações em que você utilize objetos OLE, como é este o caso, em diferentes máquinas, talvez seja necessário verificar se o objeto a ser usado está disponível e registrado corretamente. Isso evita problemas caso o Excel por exemplo, não esteja instalado na máquina, dando a você a possibilidade de fazer algo caso isto ocorra. Para isso use a função [`CLSIDFromProgID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688386%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) para verificar.

```pascal
// Inclua em Uses ActiveX;
function CheckOleObject(Classname: string): Boolean;
var
 ClassID: TCLSID;
begin
if CLSIDFromProgID(pchar(Classname), ClassID) = 0 then
  Result := True
else
  Result := False;
end;
```

Exemplo de utilização:

```pascal
if CheckOleObject('Excel.Application') = false then
  // Fazer algo aqui caso o Excel não esteja disponível
```

Em relação a inserção desse valor em uma tabela com [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/), vou ficar devendo mais detalhes sobre, porem, um dos modos possíveis para isso é o [`INSERT`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-insert.html).

Exemplo (**não testado**) com [IBQuery](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/IBQuery.TIBQuery):

```pascal
IBQuery1.close;
IBQuery1.sql.Clear;
IBQuery1.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO Tabela1 ');
IBQuery1.SQL.Add('(CNPJ, EMPRESA)');
IBQuery1.SQL.Add('VALUES');
IBQuery1.SQL.Add('(:CNPJ, :EMPRESA)');

IBQuery1.ParamByName('EMPRESA').AsString := ''; // Aqui você coloca o nome da empresa
IBQuery1.ParamByName('CNPJ').AsString := '';    // Aqui o CNPJ da empresa

IBQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

Comment: Funcionou conforme o esperado, faltou a parte do firebird mas essa parte eu mesmo faço pois é tranquilo pra mim. Muito obrigado amigo.

Comment: Muito bom :) +1 Parabens

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Obrigado. Depois vou adicionar mais algumas informações. =)

Answer (score 2):

Não tenho muito conhecimento em `Object Pascal` ou Delphi, mas vou tentar fornecer uma resposta razoável.

### Segurança com o arquivo original

O motivo disto é para evitar dois aplicativos acessarem o mesmo arquivo, o Excel cria um *LOCK* no arquivo e isto faz gerar alguns bloqueios e mesmo quando não está com o *LOCK*, pode haver conflito se o seu software estiver trabalhando o XLS ao mesmo tempo que no Excel for clicado <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (Salvar).

Para não haver conflitos a melhor maneira é gerar uma cópia do arquivo, para isto usei está função (fonte: http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=385):

```
function GetTempFile(const Extension: string): string;
var
  Buffer: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
  repeat
    GetTempPath(SizeOf(Buffer) - 1, Buffer);
    GetTempFileName(Buffer, '~', 0, Buffer);
    Result := ChangeFileExt(Buffer, Extension);
  until not FileExists(Result);
end;
```

### Selecionando o arquivo XLS

No caso optei por selecionar tanto XLS e XLSX, pois acredito que seja mais provável usar o formato mais recente (principalmente se tratando de um software para Windows), desta maneira, assim é possível dar suporte para ambos formatos (dependendo da versão instalada do Excel):

```
var
  selectedFile: String;

PromptForFileName(selectedFile, 'Documento do Excel (*.xls, *.xlsx)|*.xls; *.xlsx', '', 'Selecione...', 'C:\', False)
```

### Lendo o arquivo XLS

Criei uma função para leitura (com senha e sem senha) combinado a função `GetTempFile`, ela retorna `Boolean` e o parâmetro `var handler` retorna o arquivo aberto. Para abrir um arquivo sem senha faça algo como `openExcel(handler; 'arquivo.xls'; '');`, com senha `openExcel(handler; 'arquivo.xls'; 'senha');`

```
function openExcel(var handler: Variant; selectedFile: String; pass: String): Boolean;
begin
  EndExcel();

  tmpFile := GetTempFile('.~tp');

  CopyFile(pchar(selectedFile), pchar(tmpFile), true);

  xlsExcel := CreateOLEObject('Excel.Application');
  xlsExcel.Visible := False;

  try
    handler := xlsExcel.WorkBooks.Open(selectedFile, Password := password, ReadOnly := True);
    Result := True;
  except
    showmessage('excepet');
    EndExcel();
    handler := Unassigned;
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

### Fechando o XLS

Note que o processo `EXCEL.EXE` não termina, mesmo que feche o aplicativo, por se tratar de um `ActiveX`, ou seja ele roda separado, para isto criei uma função chamada `EndExcel` para finalizar sempre for necessário e limpar a variável.

```
procedure EndExcel();
begin
  if VarIsEmpty(xlsExcel) = False then
  begin
    xlsExcel.Quit;
    xlsExcel := Unassigned;
  end;

  if tmpFile <> '' then
  begin
    DeleteFile(tmpFile);
  end;
end;
```

### Autenticando o XLS

A autenticação as vezes vai se fazer necessária e é um requisito que você mencionou, para isto criei um evento que trabalha combinado com o `openExcel`, para chama-lo basta executar `authExcel('arquivo.xls');`. Irá abrir um `prompt` para selecionar um arquivo, a própria função irá testar se é necessário senha, se for necessário então irá aparecer um prompt pedindo para digitar a tal senha, segue a função:

```
function authExcel(fileStr: String) : Variant;
var
  password: String;
  buttonSelected: Integer;
  xlsTmp: Variant;
begin
  password := InputBox('Autenticação', 'Senha do arquivo', '');
  if password = '' then
  begin
      ShowMessage('Nenhuma senha digitada');
      Result := Unassigned;
  end
  else            
  begin
    if openExcel(xlsTmp, fileStr, password) then
    begin
      Result := xlsTmp
    end
    else
    begin
      buttonSelected := MessageDlg('Senha inválida, tentar novamente?', mtCustom, [mbYes, mbCancel], 0);
      if buttonSelected = mrYes then
      begin
        Result := authExcel(fileStr);
      end
      else
      begin
        ShowMessage('Cancelado');
        Result := Unassigned;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

### Buscando na primeira coluna

Eu iria fazer uma `array` que traria todos resultados, mas optei por criar função com busca por "coringa" (se necessário) ou por palavra chave, essa busca é feita na coluna que desejar, mas como o caso é pesquisar na primeira então adicionei um parâmetro para mudar conforme a necessidade, está função retorna um array multidimensional deste tipo `array of array of string`

A função é assim:

```
findInExcel(xls: Variant; col: Integer; query: String; limitCols: Integer): TStringArrayArray
```

`col` se refere a coluna que deseja consultar, `query` vai ser a pesquisa e `limitCols` é para evitar copiar colunas extras a direita, note também que após usar `findInExcel` usei o `EndExcel()`, porém remova esta parte se você ainda vier a necessitar do `handler` (xls: Variant), segue exemplos de uso:

1. Buscar na primeira coluna, que contenha a palavra `a` e sem limite de colunas a direita (a própria função vai tentar limitar):

   ```
   findInExcel(handler, 1, 'a', 0);
   EndExcel();
   ```
2. Busca na primeira coluna, que contenha qualquer coisa (a função vai tentar evitar colunas vazias) e com limite de 4 colunas a direita:

   ```
   findInExcel(handler, 1, '*', 4);
   EndExcel();
   ```
3. Busca na segunda coluna, que comece com a letra A (por exemplo `A0001`, `A0002`) e com limite de 5 colunas a direita:

   ```
   findInExcel(handler, 2, 'A*', 5);
   EndExcel();
   ```
4. Busca na primeira coluna, que termine com a letra B (por exemplo `0001B`, `2B`) e sem limite de colunas a direita (a própria função vai tentar limitar):

   ```
   findInExcel(handler, 1, '*B', 0);
   EndExcel();
   ```

### Como configurar o arquivo `pas`:

- Adicione aos `uses` o `ComObj` e `StrUtils` para as funções funcionarem
- Adicione aos `type` isto `TStringArrayArray = Array of Array of String;`
- Adicione as variáveis globais `xlsExcel: Variant;` e `tmpFile: String;`

### Exemplo de uso (testado no Delphi7):

Não vou falar do FireBird, pois não sei como é a sua estrutura/modelagem, então vou presumir que o problema é obter os dados do Excel apenas.

No exemplo cada vez que é feito um loop no primeiro `for` é retornado uma linha do Excel e a cada vez que é feito um loop no segundo `for` é retornado uma coluna:

```
  for i := 0 to High(encontrados) do
  begin
    for j := 0 to High(encontrados[i]) do
    begin
  if encontrados[i][j] <> '' then //Evita dados em branco
    ShowMessage('Linha: ' + IntToStr(i) + ' - Coluna: ' + IntToStr(j) + ' = ' + encontrados[i][j]);
    end;
  end;
```

Para um arquivo xls assim:

```
+----+----+----+----+
| a1 | a2 | a3 | a4 |
+----+----+----+----+
| b1 | b2 | b3 | b4 |
+----+----+----+----+
```

O exemplo irá retornar isto (note que em arrays os números sempre começam do `0`, se precisar para resolver isto no seu banco de dados basta adicionar `+1`):

> Linha: 0 - Coluna: 0 = a1
>
> Linha: 0 - Coluna: 1 = a2
>
> Linha: 0 - Coluna: 2 = a3
>
> Linha: 0 - Coluna: 3 = a4
>
> Linha: 1 - Coluna: 0 = b1
>
> Linha: 1 - Coluna: 1 = b2
>
> Linha: 1 - Coluna: 2 = b3
>
> Linha: 1 - Coluna: 3 = b4

Exemplo completo:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ComObj, StrUtils;

type
  TStringArrayArray = Array of Array of String;
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  tmpFile: String;
  selectedFile: String;
  password: String; 
  xlsExcel: Variant;
  xlsDocument: Variant;
  consultarEm: Integer;
  encontrados: TStringArrayArray;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure EndExcel();
begin
  if VarIsEmpty(xlsExcel) = False then
  begin
    xlsExcel.Quit;
    xlsExcel := Unassigned;
  end;

  if tmpFile <> '' then
  begin
    DeleteFile(tmpFile);
  end;
end;

function GetTempFile(const Extension: String): String;
var
  Buffer: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
  repeat
    GetTempPath(SizeOf(Buffer) - 1, Buffer);
    GetTempFileName(Buffer, '~', 0, Buffer);
    Result := ChangeFileExt(Buffer, Extension);
  until not FileExists(Result);
end;

function openExcel(var handler: Variant; selectedFile: String; pass: String): Boolean;
begin
  EndExcel();

  tmpFile := GetTempFile('.~tp');

  CopyFile(pchar(selectedFile), pchar(tmpFile), true);

  xlsExcel := CreateOLEObject('Excel.Application');
  xlsExcel.Visible := False;

  try
    handler := xlsExcel.WorkBooks.Open(selectedFile, Password := password, ReadOnly := True);
    Result := True;
  except
    showmessage('excepet');
    EndExcel();
    handler := Unassigned;
    Result := False;
  end;
end;

function authExcel(fileStr: String) : Variant;
var
  password: String;
  buttonSelected: Integer;
  xlsTmp: Variant;
begin
  password := InputBox('Autenticação', 'Senha do arquivo', '');
  if password = '' then
  begin
      ShowMessage('Nenhuma senha digitada');
      Result := Unassigned;
  end
  else            
  begin
    if openExcel(xlsTmp, fileStr, password) then
    begin
      Result := xlsTmp
    end
    else
    begin
      buttonSelected := MessageDlg('Senha inválida, tentar novamente?', mtCustom, [mbYes, mbCancel], 0);
      if buttonSelected = mrYes then
      begin
        Result := authExcel(fileStr);
      end
      else
      begin
        ShowMessage('Cancelado');
        Result := Unassigned;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

function findInExcel(xls: Variant; col: Integer; query: String; limitCols: Integer) : TStringArrayArray;
var
  pages: Integer;
  currentPage: Integer;
  currentLine: Integer;
  currentCol: Integer;
  found: Integer;
  lines: Integer;
  cols: Integer;
  cells: Integer;
  dataRow: String;
  resultados: TStringArrayArray;
  coringa: Boolean;
  coringaReverse: Boolean;
  findAll: Boolean;
begin
  if col < 1 then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Coluna para consulta não especificada');
    Result := null;
  end
  else
  begin
    pages := xls.Worksheets.Count;
    if pages > 0 then
    begin
      cells := 0;
      found := 0;
      cols  := 0;
      currentPage := 0;

      findAll := '*' = query;
      coringa := AnsiPos('*', query) > 0;
      coringaReverse := AnsiPos('*', query) = 1;

      query := StringReplace(query, '*', '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);

      while currentPage < pages do
      begin
        currentLine := 0;
        lines := xls.Worksheets[currentPage + 1].UsedRange.Rows.Count;
        while currentLine < lines do
        begin
          dataRow := xls.Worksheets[currentPage + 1].Cells[currentLine + 1, col];

          if coringaReverse then
            dataRow := ReverseString(dataRow);

          if (findAll and (dataRow <> '')) or (coringa and (AnsiPos(query, dataRow) = 1)) or (dataRow = query) then
          begin
            cells := xls.Worksheets[currentPage + 1].UsedRange.Cells.Count;
            found := found + 1;

            if cols < cells then
              cols := cells;

            if (limitCols > 0) and (cells > limitCols) then
              cols := limitCols;

            if cells > 0 then
              SetLength(resultados, found, cols);

            currentCol := 0;

            while (currentCol < cols) and (cells > 0) do
            begin
             dataRow := xls.Worksheets[currentPage + 1].Cells[currentLine + 1, currentCol + 1];
             resultados[found - 1][currentCol] := xls.Worksheets[currentPage + 1].Cells[currentLine + 1, currentCol + 1];
             currentCol := currentCol + 1;
            end;
          end;
          currentLine := currentLine + 1;
        end;
        currentPage := currentPage + 1;
      end;
      Result := resultados;
    end
    else
    begin
      ShowMessage('Não há páginas neste documento');
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  EndExcel();

  //Remova esta parte se quiser
  if MessageDlg('Deseja realmente sair?', mtCustom, [mbYes, mbCancel], 0) = mrCancel then
    Action := caNone;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  j: Integer;
begin
  if PromptForFileName(selectedFile, 'Documento do Excel (*.xls, *.xlsx)|*.xls; *.xlsx', '', 'Selecione...', 'C:\', False) then
  begin
    if openExcel(xlsDocument, selectedFile, '') = False then
      xlsDocument := authExcel(selectedFile);

    if VarIsEmpty(xlsDocument) = False then
    begin
      consultarEm := StrToInt(InputBox('Infomarção', 'Qual coluna gostaria de consultar', '1'));
      if consultarEm > 0 then
      begin
        encontrados := findInExcel(xlsDocument, consultarEm, '*', 4);
        EndExcel();

        if High(encontrados) = -1 then
        begin
          ShowMessage('Não foram encontrados resultados');
        end
        else
        begin
              for i := 0 to High(encontrados) do
              begin
                for j := 0 to High(encontrados[i]) do
                begin
              if encontrados[i][j] <> '' then //Evita dados em branco
                ShowMessage('Linha: ' + IntToStr(i) + ' - Coluna: ' + IntToStr(j) + ': ' + encontrados[i][j]);
                end;
              end;
        end;
      end
      else
      begin
        ShowMessage('Coluna inválida');
      end;
    end;
  end
  else            
  begin
      ShowMessage('Nenhum arquivo selecionado');
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Para quem começou a programar ontem em Delphi, Great Job!

Comment: @QMechanic73 Obrigado, gostei do estilo de "tipagem" do `Object Pascal`. Uma duvida, pelo que entendi `Delphi` além de ser o IDE também é o nome da "linguagem" (ou seria framework) derivada do `Object Pascal` usada após o Delphi7?

Comment: Delphi é somente a IDE para Object Pascal, porém como Delphi é muito usado, muitos preferem chamar a linguagem assim, uma outra IDE bastante usada é o Lazarus. =]

Comment: @QMechanic73 Entendi. Sobre o Lazarus, aparentemente é cross-platform, isso realmente é incrível. Até mais e obrigado.